# Convert from double to string in STATISTICA query node

Tags: sql, oracle, casting

EDIT: We've decided that, rather than a syntax issue, this is *probably* a bug. I got around it for now by using ToString(x) in a Data Transform node connected to the Query node.

I need to convert a variable from double to string (or failing that some text data type) in a STATISTICA query node--the node you can use in a Workspace to query other Workspace nodes.
Apparently it's Oracle SQL, but nothing I've found online/guessed is working:

```
char(x),

string(x),

text(x),

cast(x as char),

cast(x as string),

cast(x as text),

to_char(x),

to_string(x),

to_text(x),
```

Here is the original SQL (edited b/c security):

```
SELECT tbl1.var,tbl2.Lot_Number_1,tbl3.var2,tbl4.Lot_Number_2,tbl5.var2,tbl6.Lot_No_3,tbl7.var2,tbl8.Lot_No_4,tbl9.var2,tbl10.Lot_Number_5,tbl11.var2,tbl12.Lot_Number_6,tbl13.Lot_Number_7,tbl14.var2
FROM [All the tables; inner joins--is working fine]
```

And here is where I try to use one of the above on a lot number variable:

```
SELECT tbl1.var,cast(tbl2.Lot_Number_1 as string),tbl3.var2,tbl4.Lot_Number_2,tbl5.var2,tbl6.Lot_No_3,tbl7.var2,tbl8.Lot_No_4,tbl9.var2,tbl10.Lot_Number_5,tbl11.var2,tbl12.Lot_Number_6,tbl13.Lot_Number_7,tbl14.var2
FROM [All the tables; inner joins--is working fine]
```

This is the error message I get:

```
"Error with node '[Node name]':Parse error

Expected tokens: < COMMA > , < FROM >

Last token: '('(L), 'to_string'(P)

Last node: 'ColumnName: TableName.{Identifier or *}'

-------Parse trace-------

SELECT

IDENTIFIER -> TableName

DOT > IDENTIFIER

IDENTIFIER -> Identifier

Identifier -> Identifier_QuotesAllowed

Identifier_QuotesAllowed -> Identifier_QuotesAllowedOrStar

TableName DOT Identifier_QuotesAllowedOrStar -> ColName

ColName -> ValueOrColName

ValueOrColName -> SelectExpressio"
```

(SelectExpressio is not a typo)

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add the SQL statement please?

Comment: You can use `CAST()` or you can use `TO_CHAR()`.

Comment: @DavidFaber I've tried both--does the fact that they are not working indicate a bug/something else I'm getting wrong?

Comment: `cast(tbl2.Lot_Number_1 as string)` - you should be using `CAST(tbl2.lot_number_1 AS VARCHAR2)`

Comment: @DavidFaber Thanks! That did not work either, and given the content of the error message (which seems to be partially asking for a FROM), I'm starting to wonder if the issue isn't the cast syntax, but rather the fact that I am modifying/converting[/whatever the appropriate general verb is] objects in this query, period. Do you happen to know a way to test or fix that?